# setTimeout() alternative example

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I recently read up on how `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are unreliable.

Many people on stack overflow have this problem, but not many general examples are given, **especially not specifically for `setTimeout()`**

Here's what I need:

A timeout that will that will execute doSomething() in the most accurate way possible.

I.e., `alternativeTimeout(doSomething, 1500);`

Thank you, and if you have any questions, please comment!

*Most of the people reading this will think it is a duplicate, but through the answers I've searched for there is not example like the one I am asking for.

Comment: What is "reliability" for you? In a non-realtime environment you cannot get any guarantees about when something is to be handled. "Thank you, and if you have any questions, please comment!" --- do you actually have a question though? :-S

Comment: @zerkms I just meant that it will execute exactly on 1500 milliseconds

Comment: It's impossible in a non-realtime OS. A process can be pre-empted at any time, so nothing can be guaranteed by a runtime.

Comment: @zerkms Is there something that will at least get the time closer to what I want rather than varying so much?

Comment: In engineering "as much as possible" is not a measurable unit. `setTimeout` is the best you have, accept it.

Comment: @zerkms Alright. Thank you

Comment: that's impossible. engine is engine. do we need to calculate each client-side engine, calculate the browser speed, compare with cmos clock or even the real-life clock to get the average delay (which is also unreliable) then make the custom alternative function? those are absolutely not a solution. `setTimeout` is the best we have for now ... in this century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library for this exact need. It's called later.js and is available for the client and server side. It is basically a high-level wrapper around setTimeout with cron-like scheduling. Here is an [example](https://bunkat.github.io/later/execute.html) taken from the project's site:

```
function test() {
  console.log(new Date());
}

var sched = later.parse.recur().every(5).minute(),
t = later.setTimeout(test, sched);
```

Comment: This will not delay?